# Converting sub-query to join to create a view

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a nested SQL query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM asset_status
    ORDER BY session_id DESC
) tmp
GROUP BY asset_id, workflow_element_id
```

I would like to create a view from this query but MySQL doesn't seem to allow subqueries in views. How can convert this to a join?

Comment: What are the columns of asset_status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does allow sub-queries in views.  What you can't do, is `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY a, b`

Have you tried...  (I'll assume this isn't your whole query so I'll make the minimum possible changes)

```
SELECT asset_id, workflow_element_id
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM asset_status
    -- ORDER BY session_id DESC   (Removed as innefective in a view)
) tmp
GROUP BY asset_id, workflow_element_id
```

Also, note that the ORDER BY in the inner query is innefective (and possibly even dis-allowed), as the outer query is then allowed to re-order it (it won't *always* come back in a different order, but this layout doesn't *guarnatee* the order you seem to want).  Even in the outer query, it *may* cause your results to be order when using the view, but again the optimiser is allowed to re-order the results.  Unless the ORDER BY is in the query using the view, the order is never *absolutely guaranteed*...

```
SELECT * FROM view ORDER BY x
```

Finally, you tagged this as a LEFT JOIN question.  If you have a more complete example of the code, I'm sure someone will suggest an alternative layout.  But I'm off out for a few days now.  Good luck! :)

Comment: This is MySQL, not SQLServer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for subquery since the inner order by is not guaranteed to be used at all. You can write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT asset_id, workflow_element_id
FROM asset_status
```

If you need to order by `session_id` you would have to include it in an aggregate, `max` for example. (or in the group by)

```
SELECT asset_id, workflow_element_id
FROM asset_status
GROUP BY asset_id, workflow_element_id
ORDER BY MAX(session_id) DESC
```

Comment: I added the subquery only for the order by. Since you say that order by is not guaranteed, I will try the aggregate `max`

Answer (score 0):

According to [the MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), you can create views that use sub-queries, but not in the From clause.

Therefore, I think you need to create your view like the following:

```
select a.* 
from asset_status a
join (select asset_id, workflow_element_id, MAX(session_id) session_id
      from asset_status
      group by asset_id, workflow_element_id) sq
  on a.session_id = sq.session_id
```

However, it probably won't perform as well as your original query.

Comment: How does your query handle the sort order of session_id? This query does not return the expected records. I am trying to retrieve the status of an asset for different workflows. These results need to be from the latest session.

Comment: @apurv: Your original query appeared to have been designed to return the most recent asset_status record (ie. with the highest session_id) for each combination of asset_id and workflow_element_id. The use of max(session_id), combined with grouping, should select the highest session_id per combination of asset_id and workflow_element_id. How do the results from this query differ from the expected results? Can you include some sample data in your question?